# How to format an array so it will look like a matrix when printing?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

How do you format an 2 dimensional array so that prints out a sort of matrix "Style".

For example in this snippet of code array is getting two the product of two ,two dimensional int arrays.

Say a 2x2 matrix that is like this

```
   59 96

   78 51
```

In the command prompt when printed out it ends up being displayed like this

59 96 78 51

how do you make it be display in the matrix type format of row and columns.

2X2 is just an example in this program the 2d arrays have to be greater or equal to 50.

```
            else
           {
            int[][] array; 
           //this will hold the multiplied thing

            array=multiply(matrix,matrix2);

            System.out.println("this is the result of the multiplication");
            //print out the array
            for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
            {
                for( int j=0; j< col2; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(array[i][j] + " \t");

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but such formating in pretty way is not so easy.

```
for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {

        for( int j=0; j< col2; j++) {

            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " \t");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I think this will only work as long as the numbers are short, if one number goes over the tabulator line and the number in the next line doesn't, it will shift one line strangely.

Comment: That's what I've meant by "formatting in pretty way". He'll discover it soon :P

Answer (score 0):

Add one line to your code:

```
System.out.println("this is the result of the multiplication");
        //print out the array
        for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            for( int j=0; j< col2; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " \t");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

or making a method like this

```
  public static void printMatrix(int[][] mat) {
  System.out.println("Matrix["+mat.length+"]["+mat[0].length+"]");
       int rows = mat.length;
       int columns = mat[0].length;
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               System.out.printf("%4d " , mat[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.println();
  }
```

and call it from your main program

```
printMatrix(array);
```